# run android apps (apps for the dalvik JVM) on J2ME

Tags: java, emulator

This question is an extension of this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/93844/87784).

Since I couldn’t be able to find something for the bluetooth standard on android, the idea is to be able to run android apps on my phone so I would be able to connect my tablet to internet over bluetooth using a custom protocol instead of the standard one *(there are many free working apps for using reverse-tethering between two android devices. but non of them use the official DUN service)*.

For those who don’t understand, there are several java platforms :

- The [first](https://www.java.com/fr/download/) is the one most people use on there computers
- the [second](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/index.html) is based on the first. It use the same executable format *(jar files)* and are installed by jad files which are text based *(It also sign the code with a certificate)*. You can use a jar file directly *(without a jad file)*, but you won’t be able to perform some kind of operations like connecting to internet or accessing files on the device.
- The next one was created several years later after java ME. It have no real link to Sun or Oracle. the format used by apk applications. While the Sun/Oracle versions where only a platforms, Google designed it as a complete OS. It is the Dalvik JVM.

So is there a jad for running, apk applications?

Comment: I know this represent a typical case of the XYZ problem, but nobody seems to be able to solve X, and I think this question can help other peoples with different problems. There are already many way to run J2ME/jad with apk files. I want to run apk files with jar files installed by jad files.